# .net core, sharing views and controllers, loading views from .net framework project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have .net standard 2.0 library(sdk=Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor), called SelfHost. SelfHost starts kestrel web host server with MVC. SelfHost contains also controllers and views. Building produces SelfHost.Views.dll, controllers from SelfHost are loaded, everything till this point works fine. And the tricky part: i want SlefHost to also load controllers and views from client app(assembly that references this library). 
SelfHost detects controllers from another assembly using:

```
services.AddApplicationPart(clientAssembly)
```

Detecting views from another assembly is realized by:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(clientAssembly));
```

In this approach, views build action has to be set to "Embedded Resource"

**Case 1:**

Running .net core console app(sdk=Microsoft.NET.Sdk) that uses SelfHost, without adding additional controllers and views to console app. So we have clean console app with controllers and views only from SelfHost.

**Result 1**:
Everything works fine. I have access to controllers, views are returned.

**Case 2:** 
 Running .net core console app(sdk=Microsoft.NET.Sdk.**Razor**) that uses SelfHost, **with** adding additional controllers and views to console app. So we have console app with controllers/views from selfhost and controllers/views from console app.

**Result 2** 
Everything works fine. I have access to SelfHost and console app controllers. Views from SelfHost and console app are returned.

**Case 3:**
Running .net core console app(sdk=Microsoft.NET.Sdk, without Razor) that uses SelfHost, **with** adding additional controllers and views to console app. So we have console app with controllers/views from selfhost and controllers/views from console app.

**Result 3:**

When trying to access view from console app i am getting:

```css
One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Jakis_Index), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml")]
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Jakis_Index))]
Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
+
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Jakis_Index), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml")]
Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
+
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Jakis_Index), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml")]
Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
+
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Jakis_Index), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml")]
Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
+
[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Jakis_Index))]
Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
+
[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Jakis_Index))]
The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
    using System;
The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
    using System.Collections.Generic;
The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
    using System.Linq;
The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
    [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorSourceChecksumAttribute(@"SHA1", @"3884152d0999a8c1c979e05ec6b3e584997f3684", @"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml")]
Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
+
    [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorSourceChecksumAttribute(@"SHA1", @"3884152d0999a8c1c979e05ec6b3e584997f3684", @"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml")]
Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
+
    [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorSourceChecksumAttribute(@"SHA1", @"3884152d0999a8c1c979e05ec6b3e584997f3684", @"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml")]
Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
+
    [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorSourceChecksumAttribute(@"SHA1", @"3884152d0999a8c1c979e05ec6b3e584997f3684", @"/Views/Jakis/Index.cshtml")]
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
    public class _Views_Jakis_Index : global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<dynamic>
Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
+
    public class _Views_Jakis_Index : global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<dynamic>
Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
+
    public class _Views_Jakis_Index : global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<dynamic>
The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>
+
        public async override global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync()
The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
        public async override global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync()
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider { get; private set; }
Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider { get; private set; }
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper Url { get; private set; }
Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper Url { get; private set; }
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IViewComponentHelper Component { get; private set; }
Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IViewComponentHelper Component { get; private set; }
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IJsonHelper Json { get; private set; }
Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IJsonHelper Json { get; private set; }
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<dynamic> Html { get; private set; }
Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<dynamic> Html { get; private set; }
Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<dynamic> Html { get; private set; }
Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<dynamic> Html { get; private set; }
Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
+
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<dynamic> Html { get; private set; }
'_Views_Jakis_Index.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method found to override
+
        public async override global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync()
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
+
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
```

This error also occurs when console app is on .net framework stack. 
I suppose this is because there is no available razor sdk to compile this views. 
Is there any solution to that problem? I would like to use this SelfHost library also in .net framework components, where i cannot set sdk to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.